# python3 insert into dictionnary using pymysql

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

I create a small programme using pymysql to connect to mysql database when i execute query to insert into db like this :

```
self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(table1, table2) VALUES (%s, s%)", ('values1','values2'))
```

the query execute perfectly but went i try to insert dictionnary like this

```
self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(%s) VALUES (%s)" % (",".join(dict.keys(), ",".join(dict.values()))))
```

i have this error

> pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '://www.url.com' at line 1")

i try to write like this

```
self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(%s) VALUES (%s)", (",".join(dict.keys()), ",".join(dict.values())))
```

but now i have this error

> pymysql.err.InternalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'values1' in 'field list'")

Comment: Is `values1` a column in table `test`?

Comment: for the table test, first column is table1 and the values is values1 and seconde column is tables2 and values is values2

Comment: you should never use name of builtins for your objects

Comment: May I see the output of `print(",".join(dict.keys()))` and `print(",".join(dict.values()))`.

Comment: when i put `",".join(dict.keys())` into varable it's work